# onKeyDown not working in andEngine

Tags: android, andengine

Well, i'm trying to implement key events in andEngine based program. Just for the purpose of testing, i'm trying to exit the app on press of the back button with the below code

```
 @Override
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          try {
              System.exit(0);
} catch (Exception e) {

            Debug.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
```

When i run the app, i don't see it exiting on press of the back button on my keyboard's back button. I'm testing this functionality on Emulator with hardware keyboard enabled. Why nothing happens on the press of the back button? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tested implementing onBackPressed() method too? try using finish() instead of System.exit

Comment: yes! but it didn't work!

Comment: You've tried both tips? Are you debugging? I mean, the method is executed?

Comment: no! the method doesn't execute. I don't see anything in Logcat when i add this line  Log.i("pressed","dsasdads"); to the method

Comment: This is the root cause :) Are you extending which class?

Comment: I'm extending the class with SimpleBaseGameActivity

Comment: best debuging on the real device) maybe emulator is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            try {
                finish(); // added
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Debug.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
            return true; // added
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Try this.It may help you

Comment: Please explain your changes (what you added). It might help Hitesh to understand why he/she did not achieve this.